# How to layer photos in vue using vue-kinesis

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to layer a bunch of images and stack them to create a sort of depth effect using the mouse position. I opted to use vue-kinesis but I'm not able to layer the images. The effect I'm trying to achieve is available on my github [vue-pano repo](https://github.com/joeljose24/webflow_pano)

This is similar to what's done on the kinesis demo page in the photography display where a few images are stacked on top of eachother the main picture has a depth effect[Kinesis demo](https://aminerman.com/kinesis/#/)

Any alternate solution would also be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried the docs? There are example of how to use it with images
https://www.aminerman.com/kinesis

Comment: @Abregre yes I tried copying the examples but I haven't been able to replicate the effect :/